# С++, динамический массив с генератором случайных чисел и нахождение максимума на четных позициях

Tags: c++, функции, динамические-массивы

Задача такая, написать программу на языке С++ для создания динамического массива `A[N]`. Заполнить массив с помощью генератора случайных чисел (получение случайного числа в интервале `[a,b]` оформить как функцию `(a=-30,b=30)`). Найти максимум среди всех элементов массива расположенных на четных позициях.
Определение максимума оформить как функцию. Код приведенный ниже работает неправильно и не соответствует условию задачи. Во первых массив не динамический, во вторых неправильно работает. Если кто-то что-то знает и умеет, выражу свою признательность за оказанную помощь.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;
void minimum()
{ int n,k;
int A[100] ;
cout<<"n= "; cin>>n;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
A[i]=rand()%60-30;
cout<<"max["<<i<<"]="<<A[i]<<endl;
}
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
if(i%2==0 || A[i]>=k) k=A[i];
cout<<"Max znacheniye= "<<k;
}
int main()
{
minimum();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Во первых массив не динамический...".  Так создайте его динамическим....?:)

Comment: не умею, нужен пример

Comment: да и в любом случае код выдает неверный результат

Comment: Да, у вас проблем много. Например объявляете  int k, а там мусор(не известно что) и используете для сравнения... Например вы должны написать две функции(по условию задачи).

Answer (score 1):

В вашем вопросе не содержится конкретный вопрос, потому он не может являться полезным вопросом, и ставлю свой минус. Однако  я решил ответить вам как нужно действовать, чтобы вы начали понимать как подойти к решению вопросов и обращали внимание на некоторые аспекты безопасного кода (по хорошему, на С++ есть решения проще и безопаснее...).

И так, начинаем разбирать условия задачи:

> Написать программу на языке С++ для создания динамического массива

Так как нужно написать функцию, то можно придумать ей имя.

> Заполнить массив с помощью генератора случайных чисел (получение
> случайного числа в интервале [a,b]

Значит мы имеем константный размер(размер всегда без знаковый), константный интервал и мы должны получить массив. Так и напишем:

```
int* create_array(const unsigned , const int, const int);
```

У генератора псевдослучайных чисел много проблем(особенно при много поточности, но это уже другой вопрос), поэтому в С++ обычно используются генераторы из `<random>`. Но так как вашей задачи не интересуют эти проблемы, то можно использовать и его.

Как получить интервал [a,b]? Это число от  ноль  до
значения интервала(b - a + 1)  плюс начало диапазона:
И так, наша функция создает динамический массив  и возвращает указатель на него. Случай, где  необходимо оставить комментарий перед функцией(комментария тоже часть программирования):

```
//Предупреждения!
//№1 Функция создает  массив генератором псевдослучайных чисел
//№2 Не забывать освобождать память после использования
int* create_array(const unsigned size, const int a, const int b)
{
    int* ptr = new int[size]; 
    const int span = (b - a + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        ptr[i] = a + rand() % span;
    return ptr;
}
```

Остается написать функцию для нахождения максимума из  элементов по четным индексам. Тут уже просто нужно пройти по четным индексам, но для этого нужно определить последний четный индекс, потому что размер может быть нечетным:

```
int find_max(int* array, const unsigned size)
{
    //пусть максимальное число есть первый элемент
    int max = array[0];
    //определим последный четный  индекс    
    unsigned last_index = (size % 2) ? size - 1 : size;
    //и пройдем по четным индексам начиная со второго четного
    for (unsigned i = 2; i < last_index; i += 2)
        if (max < array[i])
            max = array[i];
    return max;
}
```

Надеюсь использовать функции и освобождать память вы сами сможете, если немного затруднитесь работать...